# Set Image on Application Startup

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm currently developing an Obj-C Desktop application which gets a string from an URL and displays an image regarding to the recieved string.

```
//I know this one won't work, but it's just for example
NSString * text = [NSString stringFromUrl:@"http://example.com"];
NSString * imageName = [text splitStringIntoSome];
//imageName is now @"A.png"

[imageViewOutlet setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

So, the problem is, I want to do that when the application launches, but when I copy this code into my applicationDidFinishLaunching, just nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately since URL requests are performed asynchronously, it requires a bit more code to do this. Here is a good example straight from Apple:
[Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Except in `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` you would create an image using NSImage's `- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data`

Comment: Why initWithData instead of imageNamed:(NSString *)aString

Comment: "imageNamed:" takes an image name or a filename from your bundle. NSURLConnection returns NSData so that's what you have to use

Comment: No, I get the image name as url content. The image itself loads correctly when I call the function per ButtonClick, it just doesn't work when I use it in my app delegate